# looping through two files and count string occurrences of 2nd file in lines of first file using python

Tags: python-3.x

Thank you for your help and Apologies for my naiveness
I need to generate permutation of some words (A T G C ) actually nucleotides for di-composition (eg AA AT AG AC), tri-composition (AAA AAT AAC AAG), tetra, penta etc (one at a time) and then check in the other file that contains sequences with some values the count of occurrences of each permutation. I generated the permutation list. 
Now I need to loop through the sequences only (splitting the sequences from values) for counting each of the permutation generated above and get the output in new file.
But I'm getting the answer for only one sequence and not for the other sequences.

**Logic of the programme i tried to follow is :**

1. Generate the permutations of ATCG in a file1 (e.g. AT AG AC AA ...)
2. Read the generated file1 and sequence#value file (DNA_seq_val.txt)
3. Read the sequences and separate the sequences form values
4. Loop through the sequences for the permutations and print their
   occurrence with values (each separated with comma) in results file.

*Input test file= DNA_seq_val.txt
AAAATTTT#99 \n
CCCCGGGG#77\n
ATATATCGCGCG#88*\n

*Output I got is --
2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,99  AAAATTTT \n
77  CCCCGGGG\n
88  ATATATCGCGCG
Output Needed is 
2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,99  AAAATTTT \n
x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,77  CCCCGGGGx \n
x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,88  ATATATCGCGCG (where x= corresponding counts as in first line)

```
    enter code herefrom itertools import product
import os

f2 = open('TRYYY', 'a')

#********Generate the permutations start********
per = product('ACGT', repeat=2) # ATGC =nucleotides; 2= for di ntd(replace 2 with 3 fir tri ntds and so on)
f = open('myfile', 'w')
p = ""
for p in per:
    p = "".join(p)
    f.write(p + "\n")
f.close()

#********Generate the permutations ENDS********

with open('DNA_seq_val.txt', 'r+') as SEQ, open('myfile', 'r+') as TET: #open two files
    SEQ_lines = sum(1 for line in open('DNA_seq_val.txt'))      #count lines in sequences file
    #print (SEQ_lines)
    compo_lines = sum(1 for line in open('myfile'))     #count lines in composition
    #print (compo_lines)
    for lines in SEQ:
        line,val1 = lines.split("#")
        val2 = val1.rstrip('\n')
        val = str(val2)
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        length =len(line)
        #print (line)       
        #print (val)
        LIN = line, val
        #print (LIN)
        newstr = "".join((line))
        print (newstr)
        #while True:        # infinte loop
        for PER in TET:
            #print (line)
            PER = PER.rstrip('\n')
            length2 =len(PER)
            #print (length2)
            #print (line)
#           print (PER)
            C_PER  = str(line.count(PER))
#           print (C_PER)
            for R in C_PER:
                R1 = "".join(R)
                f2.write(R1+ ",")
        f2.write(val,)
        f2.write('\t')
        f2.write(line)
        f2.write('\n')
    #exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you ...apologies...for my naiveness..i'm new to coding

Comment: I have difficulties to understand your example. The input strings are compared with what exactly? What is permutated and what does the output mean?

Comment: we generated permutations of ATGC with combination of twos like AA, AT, AC, AG...(16 instances in total) in the first part of code --Generate the permutations  and wrote that in new file "myfile". Next we took both sequence file (input file above named DNA_seq_val.txt) and checked the permutations generated (myfile) to look and count in the sequences(DNA_seq_val.txt). but i processed this file first to get only words and not the # and intiger (value associated with it).

Comment: input strings are compared to two word combinations (AT AA AC AG ...) generated in first part... four letters (ATGC) are permuted ...output is the final results I got in and as file (TRYYY)